# Identical answer on two different (not duplicate) questions

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Recently I've found out that Microsoft's tool "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer" can be used to rename containers, tables and file shares in Azure after looking its [revision log](http://storageexplorer.com/releasenotes.html). And for a while I was looking for this and therefore I know that there are questions in SO with answers as "you can't" or "you have to copy". Like this question for [containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12370656/1519458) or this one for [azure tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20322535/1519458). These questions are not duplicates. However my answer to these are same as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38973311/1519458) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38973244/1519458). My last answer is deleted by a moderator with this reason.

> Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, tailor your answers to the question

If my answer is same for these questions,  do I really need to paraphrase it? These two questions are certainly not duplicates.

Comment: Exact duplicate answers raise an auto-flag for moderators. Martijn can't judge (I think as he is more into Python land) if the questions are non-dupe. Hence he errs on the safe side. So, yes, you better paraphrase identical answers.

Comment: Are you sure they are not duplicates? Just because the type of object they are renaming is not exactly the same, both questions concern Azure Storage. The point of closing posts as duplicates is to ensure the question is answered without having to duplicate answering efforts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are right in that matter. However in both questions OP's focus is different. And the new tool does not handle renaming for all storage components. For instance you cannot rename azure storage queues with it. And also the old work aroud (copying all data) is very diffirent for containers and azure table before this tool.

Comment: Then write one **good** answer addressing all those issues.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have edited the answer which you have deleted. Now it emphasizes the question. I have even edited the other answer.